# How can i prevent default in confirm dialog in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, preventdefault

I have this in my save function

```
$scope.saveData = function () {

   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save") === false) {
       return
    }


// do saving
```

Now if i use above code then i get this after clicking yes. Even if i click cancel i still get same error in firebug. But my data get saved if i click yes but error is still there.
I only see this in firefox and not in chrome.

If i remove confirm dialog then that error is gone. so its definitely related to dialog

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

SO i was thinking may be i need to

`e.preventDefault();`

How can i use that in above function. I am using like this

`ng-click = "saveData()"`

Comment: Pass `$event` to the saveData method from the view and do `$event.preventDefault()` inside saveData function. i.e `ng-click = "saveData($event)"`

Comment: @PSL can i do that in the start of function. and if eomeone click yes then i restoreDefault. is there any function to continue Default

Comment: There is no continue default, continue default is the default behavior :).. Only preventDefault which prevents the default behavior of a particular action like a form post, anchor click etc.. But i have no clue here on where do you have this ng-click.

Comment: @PSL i have this click on button called `save`. It juts gets list from Scope variables and then post to server. I tried `preventdefault1 even at the beginning of function but still my data gets posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button ng-click="saveData($event)">Save</button>
```

Firefox doesn't auto pass in the `event` for some reason, so you have to pass it from the markup.

```
$scope.saveData = function (e) {

   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to save") === false) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return;
    }
    // do saving
};
```